# How can you separate a string of numbers to single digits using division and the modulo operator?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, math

Lets say someone enter a four digit number `1234` in the console. How can you separate this number in to `1 2 3 4` using only division and the modulo operator?

```
public static void MathProblem()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type a four digit number:");
            //Ex input: 1234

            string inputNumber = Console.ReadLine();

            // I'm guessing you first need to parse the 
            // string as an int in some way?
            // And then assign it to some variable

            // Now, for seperating the digits to be: 1 2 3 4, 
            // you can (and must) use both division (/), and the remainder (%).
            // The first one will be simple, just dividing value with 1000, but
            // how about the others? (Remember, % also need to be used at least
            // once)

                Console.Write("{0},{1},{2},{3}", value/1000, ?, ?, ?;
            }
```

Any guidelines for making this possible for any given four digit input?

Comment: @Zack, Nope, that's not the case sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int num = int.Parse(inputNumber);
Console.Write(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", (num/1000) % 100, (num/100) % 10, (num/10) % 10, num % 10));
```

OR

```
List<int> listOfInts = new List<int>();
while(num > 0)
{
    listOfInts.Add(num % 10);
    num = num / 10;
}
Console.Write("{0},{1},{2},{3}", listOfInts[3], listOfInts[2], listOfInts[1], listOfInts[0]);
```

Comment: Two good solutions, which many could learn from. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 4):

Since this seems like a homework problem, I'll simply explain the method in a few steps rather than giving you the code.  Having parsed the input as an integer,

1. A number modulo 10 allows you to obtain its last digit.
2. Dividing (integer division) the number by 10 removes the last digit.
3. Repeat while the number is greater than 0.

Comment: It might be helpful to explain the parsing as well.

Answer (score 2):

No need to do this by division or modulo operators. Use LINQ. You can get an integer array using LINQ as below:

```
string inputNumber= "1234"
var intList = inputNumber.Select(digit => int.Parse(digit.ToString()));
```

Then, you can simply use it as you want like this:

```
Console.Write("{0},{1},{2},{3}", intList[0]/1000, intList[1], intList[2], intList[3]);
```

Or simply the way you wanted it using Division and Modulo Operator:

```
public int[] ParseIntString(int number)
{
    List<int> digits= new List<int>();
    while(number> 0)
    {
        digits.Add(number% 10);
        number= number/ 10;
    }
    digits.Reverse();
    return digits.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: @user814064 Updated my answer to include that one too, if someone wants to be smarter to a single line code only :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you

```
            int[] values;
        Seperate(inputNumber, out values);
        Console.Write("{0},{1},{2},{3}", values[0] / 1000, values[1], values[2], values[3]);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static void Seperate(string numbers, out int[] values)
    {
        values = new int[numbers.Length];
        for (int x = 0; x <= numbers.Length - 1; x++)
        {
            values[x] = int.Parse(numbers[x].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just started a course in coding and had this as homework as well. I did it in excel first because I thought it was easier than running code over and over and it's more a math problem than a coding one.

Say the number is 4352.

The first digit is easy, it's the integer of the number / 1000 = 4.

Then you simply multilpy by 1000 to get 4000. Remove that and you get 352. The integer of that / 100 is 3.

Then you times that by 100 to get 300 and remove that and you get 52, the integer of that / 10 is 5. Multiply that by 10 and remove that and you're left with 2.

Just read that you must use % so I suggest getting the last number as a modular of 10